# Getting IntegrityError in Django for custom ID field

Tags: django, postgresql

I am getting an error like this:

***IntegrityError at /book_table/
null value in column "resv_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 2015-01-03, bb, 23, aa@aa.com, null, e, 3, null).***

resv_id field which is the primary key field for my DB has type serial.

I declared it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Reservation"
(
  resv_id serial NOT NULL,
  resv_date date,
  resv_customer_name character varying(255),
  resv_customer_phone character varying(20),
  resv_customer_email character varying(255),
  resv_time integer, -- This value can only be an int value that goes from 0 to 23.
  resv_special_requests character varying(300),
  resv_no_ppl integer,
  resv_table integer,
  CONSTRAINT "Reservation_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (resv_id),
  CONSTRAINT resv_table_id FOREIGN KEY (resv_table)
      REFERENCES tables (table_number) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Also, the Reservation model looks like this:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    resv_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    resv_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    resv_customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    resv_customer_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    resv_customer_email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    resv_time = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    resv_special_requests = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    resv_no_ppl = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    resv_table = models.ForeignKey('Tables', db_column='resv_table', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Reservation'
```

I looked through custom primary key field in Django documentation and it seems I have done everything right but for some reason, I keep getting the aforementioned error unless i give a value to resv_id field when I am creating a new instance of the model using objects.create method.

Do you guys know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create a new instance and don't pass `resv_id` it will lead to the `IntegrityError` because `resv_id` is a primary key and isn't allowed to be empty. Im not sure why you do this because all django models have a build in [id field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys) already but you can try something like this: `resv_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`

Comment: Nice to here... :) Feel free to accept this answer so I earn some kudos.